# How to visualize a convex set is connected but not vice-versa.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Can anyone explain this graphically/intutively to me:

A *convex set* is always a *connected set* while the converse is not true....

(A convex set is a set in which every element $a,b$ belonging to the set can be written as $(1-t)a+tb$ ,this resulting element also belongs to the set itself)

Comment: What is your definition of connected?

Comment: @angryavian I follow this definition from rudin:A set is connected if it is not union of two non-empty separated sets...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E$ be a convex set and let $x \in E$. Then we may say $E = \bigcup_{y \in E} L(x,y)$ where $L(x,y) = \{ tx + (1-t)y : t \in [0,1] \}$. $L(x,y)$ is either a point or a line, so it is connected. Furthermore, $\bigcap_{y \in E} L(x,y) = \{x\}$. The union of connected sets with nonempty intersection is a connected set. Thus, $E$ is connected.

You can easily construct a connected set which is properly contained in its hull. Just consider any concave polygon in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Here's an easy example:

Let the set of dark blue points be $E$. $E$ is a connected set, but is not convex. In particular, the light blue points are present in the convex hull of $E$ but not elements of $E$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\Huge\spadesuit$$

Answer (score 1):

If your set has a star-shape in $\mathbb{R}^2$ it is connected but not convex, since the straight line between two outer points of the star is not inside the figure.